Azure DevOps Yaml, multiple library groups & powershell
Problem: I need to replace tokens in a text file during the build pipeline execution in Azure DevOps. The values for these tokens are stored in a library, also located in Azure DevOps.
The process works fine try this with a single library.
How I currently do it:
Import/load/reference the library group in the yaml file.
The yaml file then executes a powershell script, which does the replacements. The values for the tokens are available as part of the environment variables during the build.
The powershell script also does a number of other unrelated things.
I want to expand the process to cater for multiple libraries & text files. It's a one-to-one mapping of library to text file.
If I use the process decribed above, only values for the last library in the list are available as environment variables.
How can I reference all these libraries inside the powershell script? The plan is to iterate through each library, get its associated text file, make the replacements & continue on to the next library.
I've searched on the web, but can't find anything related. ChatGPT is coming back with suggestions not available in yaml, so thought I'll ask some humans.
As described in the details section.

I want to expand the process to cater for multiple libraries & text files. It's a one-to-one mapping of library to text file - have you considered running a job for each library? This might look overkill, but at least you won't have variable name conflicts.

As per the description only values for the last library in the list are available as environment variables , may i know if you have same named variable between different library variable groups? After you reference the variable group in yaml, the variable will be automatically mapped to the environment except secret variable, please make sure you used different variables for different txt. To avoid any confusion, please share some example about your library, token list, txt file, powershell script and yaml.
